# MySQL failing and very slow on importing a large file

Tags: mysql, postgresql, etl

I have a 47 GB MySQL dump of a single table:

http://dumps.wikimedia.org/commonswiki/latest/commonswiki-latest-image.sql.gz

I ultimately want it into PostgreSQL, but since I didn't figure out an easy way to transform the MySQL SQL to PostgreSQL SQL I figured, I will get it into MySQL and then write a small ETL script to do this.

I initially tried to just load it using MySQL WorkBench Data Import/Restore, but it was failing.

Now I've run `split -l 2000 commonswiki-latest-image.sql` and have 20 files of roughly 2 GB each, but it still fails with:

```
23:12:28 Restoring C:\temp\commonswiki\xaa.sql

Running: mysql.exe --defaults-extra-file="c:\users\jmurdoch\appdata\local\temp\tmpi_ltz8.cnf"  --host=127.0.0.1 --user=root --port=3306 --default-character-set=utf8 --comments --database=mediawikiimages < "C:\\temp\\commonswiki\\xaa.sql"

ERROR 2013 (HY000) at line 331: Lost connection to MySQL server during query


Operation failed with exitcode 1

00:54:17 Import of C:\temp\commonswiki\xaa.sql has finished with 1 errors
```

It's also terribly slow as it only imported 209236 rows during the nearly 2 hours, but I think there are about 20M items to import, so at that rate it would take 200 hours to import.

I'm using Windows 7, MySQL 5.6.14 and MySQL Workbench 6.

My main questions:

- Is there a script which would feed MySQL with the splitted files and perform automatic error recovery in case it times out?
- Is there a conversion tool which would convert MySQL SQL to PostgreSQL SQL without first loading it into a database?

Comment: Is this the schema you are using?

Comment: It should not take this long to load. Are you using InnoDB or myisam for these tables? How much RAM do you have on this machine? From `show variables` give us values for `innodb_buffer_pool_size`, `innodb_write_io_threads` etc.

Comment: Also see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1112069/is-there-a-faster-way-to-load-mysqldumps

Comment: I was using InnoDB with 16 GB RAM although I'm not sure how much MySQL was ready to use. 

I actually appear to have solved the issue through increasing the 'max_allowed_packet'.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using

```
max_allowed_packet = 256M
```

in MySQL config allowed to import the files without errors.

Answer (score 1):

An answer by [kresimir-plese](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1120066/kresimir-plese) to [How can I import a large (14 GB) MySQL dump file into a new MySQL database?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22155778) on Stack Overflow helped me:

> ```
> mysql -u root -p
>
> set global net_buffer_length=1000000; --Set network buffer length to a large byte number
> set global max_allowed_packet=1000000000; --Set maximum allowed packet size to a large byte number
> SET foreign_key_checks = 0; --Disable foreign key checking to avoid delays,errors and unwanted behaviour
>
> source file.sql --Import your sql dump file
>
> SET foreign_key_checks = 1; --Remember to enable foreign key checks when procedure is complete!
> ```

and from a comment by [nicolas-thery](https://stackoverflow.com/users/903840/nicolas-thery):

> Over mariadb, max values are checked:
>
> ```
> set global net_buffer_length=1048576;
> set global max_allowed_packet=1073741824;
> ```